# SOLR Cloud setup on docker with existing schema

Tags: docker, solr, apache-zookeeper

I am using a the docker compose cluster sample setup from [docker-solr-examples](https://github.com/docker-solr/docker-solr-examples/blob/master/docker-compose/docker-compose.yml)

Now, I want to add my existing core definitions to the cluster. How do i deploy my existing core definitions and managed-schema.xml to zookeeper. I presume there is a way to put the file on one node and have it automatically replicate out to the other nodes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you looked at this documentation [Using zookeeper to manage configuration](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/8_0/using-zookeeper-to-manage-configuration-files.html)
From the docker I understand that it is creating a zookeeper ensemble consisting of 3 notes and those manage 3 solr nodes.
Usually a solr installation has a few preinstalled scripts that allow you to do some maintenance. You may have to enter the cli of one of the Solr nodes and use that to upload the configuration.
Docker is only giving you the convenience to spin up the infrastructure quickly. Other maintenance tasks will still require using solr , zookeeper cli or APIs

Comment: @vvsm you are correct- my setup has nothing to do with the task i want to achieve. I phrased this question poorly. I should have asked "What is the best practice for deploying changes to zookeeper". I wish to push my config to a fileshare and have zookeeper pull them in and deploy them to all nodes.

Comment: Config changes to Solr schema are like database structure changes. This should usually be done with an application deployment. Consider setting up a script based on the Solr cli and such that its can be triggered in a CI / CD pipeline.

Comment: For your one time update of the docker based ZK, running the Solr cli script for upconfig against any one solr node is sufficient.

Answer (score 1):

Pull Solr Docker Image
sudo docker run -d -p 8983:8983 --name docker_image_name solr solr-precreate users

Access Docker Container

1. docker ps
2. docker exec -it <image_name> bash

Create New Core In Solr (hit after accessing docker container bash)
bin/solr create -c core_name

Now You can dump your data in solr cores.

Delete solr core
bin/solr create -c core_name